# Deserializing JSON Array of Object Using Restlet/Jackson

Tags: json, rest, jackson, restlet

I am using Restlet to call an API that returns a JSON Array of objects.  When making a similar call to pull back a single object, everything gets mapped correctly to the custom class, but when I pull back the array the Object is getting mapped as a LinkedHashMap instead of this custom object.  I'm sure I just need to define how to deserialize the array correctly, but I haven't figured out exactly how to do that.

```
@Get("json")
public Trait getTrait();

@Get("json")
public HashSet<Trait> getTraits();
```

The former works fine, but the latter isn't work.  Ultimately when I try to iterate through the HashSet I can this error:  java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.test.traits.Trait.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generally because type is passed as class (like `HashSet`) instead of generic type (`HashSet<Trait>`). If so, this equivalent to `HashSet<Object>`, and Jackson has no choice but to bind contents to simplest Object type available that matches which is just `java.util.Collection` of some kind.

It sounds like Restlet is not passing generic type information correctly for some reason.

There are work-arounds to this:

- Use a wrapper object, so that `List`s and `Map`s are always properties of a Java object, never root-level values. This ensures that types work, even if Restlet did not pass generic type for root value
- Sub-class `HashSet` so that you have non-generic type; Jackson can then figure out generic types for `HashSet`

For second case, you just do something like:

```
public class MyTraits extends HashSet<Trait> { }
```

and

```
@Get("json")
public MyTraits getTraits();
```

And it will work because `MyTraits` has no generic type of its own; but its super-type declaration has generic parameters that are available to Jackson.

Comment: The latter worked.  I had actually tried that, but my new collection also had generics.  As soon as I took that out everything worked.